# Traefik middleware stripprefix remove prefix not work properly

Tags: phpmyadmin, traefik

I have a phpmyadmin service in `/phpmyadmin`. I want to remove `/phpmyadmin` from request path when the request receive to phpmyadmin. With `stripprefix` middleware:

```
- "traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin.rule=Host(`example.ir`) && PathPrefix(`/phpmyadmin`)"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.phpmyadmin-path.stripprefix.prefixes=/phpmyadmin"
- "traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin.middlewares=phpmyadmin-path"
```

It works with `/phpmyadmin/` but with `/phpmyadmin`, I get lots of `404` errors because request goes to `/` path not `/phpmyadmin`

I did set `PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI: https://example.ir/phpmyadmin` in environment variables.
How can I get phpmyadmin with both `/phpmyadmin` and `/phpmyadmin/`

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to add this label?

https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/stripprefix/#forceslash

```yaml
labels:
  ...
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.example.stripprefix.forceSlash=false"
```